# Managing gestures in UIViews with differents zPosition

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, gesture

I have some UIViews positioned at differents zPositions. The idea is to have a depth sensation at the moment of presenting the views. All the views' layers are sublayers of a MainView.layer. What I want to do is adding gestures to my views, so they can respond to the gesture if they are touched.
I did this in my ViewController:

```
UIImageView *top = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"l.png"] ];
top.frame = CGRectMake(300, 500, 400, 200);
top.layer.zPosition = 100;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:view.layer];

UIImageView *mid = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"g1.png"] ];
mid.frame = CGRectMake(200, 100, 400, 800);
mid.layer.zPosition = 0;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:view.layer];

UIImageView *back = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3a.png"] ];
back.frame = CGRectMake(500, 100, 570, 800);
back.layer.zPosition = -100;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:view.layer];
```

When I try this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[back addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Tap doesnt work. Any advice?

Comment: Is 'handleTap' executing? Have you NSLogged it? Also, using @selector(handleTap:) -- note the colon -- will pass the UITapGestureRecognizer to handleTap method.

Comment: handleTap is not executing. The NSLog line I wrote there is not printed. (Thanks for the correction. I think retyping was not a good idea. In the original code the colon does appear)

Comment: Are you able to see 'back' on the screen, its 500 px xOrigin would put it 180 px off screen.

Comment: Yes, even though I don`t see the entirely view, I can see part of it. I think that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`UIGestureRecognizer` works only with views. `back` is view, but when you add in the hierarchy you only add its layer. 
I do not understand who is `view`, because you continue to change the zposition, but is not visible where it comes from.

You do not need to create a UIImageView to show an image on a layer, you can just create a layer and change its content property, like that:

```
CALayer * layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.frame = ...
layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"3a.png"].CGImage;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I said before I retype the code, I should have copied it. I already edit it. Excuse me for that. So, should I manage the gestures in the CALayer of each UIImageView?

Comment: Nope gesture are only for views not for layers. You can add the gesture to the "main view", and by checking the tap coordinates with the layers frames find in which layer happened. The deep effect that you want to achieve, would never shown if you keep everything flat. You should host everything in a special layer CATransformLayer http://www.thinkandbuild.it/introduction-to-3d-drawing-in-core-animation-part-1/

Comment: Well the effect I want to achieve is almost OK with the approach I am taking. I am using a sort of Parallax effect, allowing pan gesture horizontally, so views in different layers scroll at different speeds. Now my problem is to manage other gestures in each particular view. Is there a way to add the views but at different zPositions? not only the layers..Or should I use UIResponder to detect where the touch happened and according to that position determine which view is receving the touch? Thanks